# Problems using User model in django unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I have the following django test case that is giving me errors:

```
class MyTesting(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.u1 = User.objects.create(username='user1')
        self.up1 = UserProfile.objects.create(user=self.u1)

    def testA(self):
        ...

    def testB(self):
        ...
```

When I run my tests, `testA` will pass sucessfully but before `testB` starts, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError: column username is not unique
```

It's clear that it is trying to create `self.u1` before each test case and finding that it already exists in the Database.  How do I get it to properly clean up after each test case so that subsequent cases run correctly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`setUp`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) and [`tearDown`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) methods on Unittests are called before and after each test case. Define [`tearDown`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) method which deletes the created user.

```
class MyTesting(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.u1 = User.objects.create(username='user1')
        self.up1 = UserProfile.objects.create(user=self.u1)

    def testA(self):
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        self.up1.delete()
        self.u1.delete()
```

I would also advise to [create user profiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) using [`post_save`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal unless you really want to create user profile manually for each user.

**Follow-up** on delete comment:

From [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects):

> When Django deletes an object, it
>   emulates the behavior of the SQL
>   constraint ON DELETE CASCADE -- in
>   other words, any objects which had
>   **foreign keys pointing at the object to
>   be deleted** will be deleted along with
>   it.

In your case, user profile is pointing to user so you should delete the user first to delete the profile at the same time.

Comment: Thanks!  The problem I'm having now is that when I delete up1, the delete does not cascade and delete u1 as well, even though I've specified User as a foreign key of UserProfile. e.g. `user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)`

Comment: Actually you should delete the user in order to cascade and delete the user profile in one go, or you can delete the user profile first and then the user.

Comment: Bah... I read that not in the docs but for some reason got confused about which direction the Foreign Key was pointing...

Comment: You should not use create() to create a user. Instead use the new create_user() method. This will hash the password properly. Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user

Answer (score 10):

If you want django to automatically flush the test database after each test is run then you should extend `django.test.TestCase`, NOT `django.utils.unittest.TestCase` (as you are doing currently).

It's good practice to dump the database after each test so you can be extra-sure you're tests are consistent, but note that your tests will run slower with this additional overhead.

See the **WARNING** section in the ["Writing Tests" Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests).

Answer (score 3):

Precisely, `setUp` exists **for the very purpose** of running once before each test case.

The converse method, the one that runs once *after* each test case, is named `tearDown`: that's where you delete `self.u1` etc (presumably by just calling `self.u1.delete()`, unless you have supplementary specialized clean-up requirements in addition to just deleting the object).