# Accessing the request.user object when testing Django

Tags: django, testing, client, request

I'm trying to access the request.user object when testing my app using django's client class.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login( username="foo", password="bar")

    def test_one(self):
        response = self.client.get("/my_profile/")
        self.fail( response.request.user )
```

This will obviously fail, but it fails because response.request doesn't have a user attribute.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Is there any way to access the user object from the client instance? I want to do this in order to check if some test user's data is properly rendered. I can try to tackle this by setting up all the necessary info during setUp, but before I do that I wanted to check if I'm not just missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `response.context['user']`.

User is automatically available in the template context if you use `RequestContext`. See [auth data in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates) doc.

Otherwise i believe you should just query it:

```
 def test_one(self):
    response = self.client.get("/my_profile/")
    user = User.objects.get(username="foo")
    self.fail( user.some_field == False )
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840467/problems-using-user-model-in-django-unit-tests this uses Secator's recommendation but in the setUp and tearDown methods, just a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

This may seem a roundabout way of doing it but it can be useful.

Use [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory), its pretty straightforward. It imitates the *request* object.

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory 
from django.test.client import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username='foo', email='foo@bar', 
                    password='bar')

    def test_one(self):
        self.client.login( username="foo", password="bar")

        request = self.factory.get("/my_profile/")
        request.user = self.user

        #rest of your code

    def tearDown(self):
        self.user.delete()
```

I hope that was helpful.